# Вставка в односвязный линейный список

Tags: c++, список

Добрый день!
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Не работает в простенькой программе вставка в конец(!) линейного списка. Никак не могу понять, в чем проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct link         // один элемент списка
{
    int data;   
    link* next;     
};

class linklist  
{
private:
    link* first;
public:
    linklist()        
    { 
        first = NULL;
    }    
    void additem(int d); 
    void display();   
};

void linklist::additem(int d)    // добавление элемента (ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА)
{
    link* newlink = new link;      
    newlink -> data = d; 
    newlink -> next = NULL; 
    link* temp = new link;
    temp = first;
    while ( (temp -> next) != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    temp -> next = newlink;
}

void linklist::display()
{
    link* current = first;              
    while(current)                      
    {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;        
    }
}

void main()
{
    linklist l;

    l.additem(1);   
    l.additem(2);
    l.additem(3);
    l.additem(4);

    l.display();     
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этой строке Вы проверяете, есть ли элемент, следующий за первым. Но в самом начале первого элемента не существует

```
while ( (temp -> next) != NULL)
```

Можно добавить условие

```
if ( first != NULL ) {
    temp = first;
    while ( (temp -> next) != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    temp -> next = newlink;
}
else
        first = newlink;
```

Answer (score 4):

[[@777Julia777](/users/10499/777julia777)](/users/10499/777julia777), если Вы хотите вставлять элементы в конец односвязного списка, то имеет смысл завести в заголовке списка 2 указателя. Один на первый, а второй на последний элемент списка.

Если же список планируется только в качестве временного контейнера и порядок в нем не важен, то можно обойтись одним указателем на первый элемент и работать со списком только через этот указатель (как со стеком). Т.е. добавлять новые элементы всегда в начало (список при этом не надо просматривать) и удалять так же.

Не удержался, надергал и слегка причесал немного кода для работы с односвязными списками.
Сразу хочу заметить, что это надо рассматривать в качестве некого шаблона, не стремясь к универсальности. Обычно подобный код даже не оформляется в виде функций (и уж никак не претендует на включение в библиотеки), иногда даже указатели `tail` и `head` не оформляются в отдельную структуру, а просто путешествует по исходникам, модифицируясь в зависимости от структур данных, связываемых в подобные списки.

Обратите внимание, что функции и макросы *возвращают* в качестве значения указатель на элемент, только что вставленный в список или удаленный из него. Это часто бывает удобно при написании кода.

```
// list2.c avp 2013 кусочки кода односвязных списков
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct elem {
  struct elem *next;
  char  *data;
};

struct list {
  struct elem *head,
    *tail;
};

struct elem *
add_tail (struct list *list, struct elem *item)
{
  item->next = 0;
  if (!(list->head))
    list->head = item;
  else
    list->tail->next = item;
  return list->tail = item;
}

struct elem *
add_head (struct list *list, struct elem *item)
{
  if (!(list->head)) {
    item->next = 0;
    return list->head = list->tail = item;
  }
  item->next = list->head;
  return list->head = item;
}

struct elem *
del_head (struct list *list)
{
  struct elem *t = list->head;
  if (t) 
    if (!(list->head = t->next))
      list->tail = 0;
  return t;
}

struct elem *
del_tail (struct list *list)
{
  struct elem *t = list->head, *p = 0;
  if (t) {
    while (t != list->tail) {
      p = t;
      t = t->next;
    }
    if (list->tail = p)
      p->next = 0;
    else
      list->head = p;
  }
  return t;
}

void
prilist (const char *msg, struct elem *e)
{
  puts(msg);

  while (e) {
    puts(e->data);
    e = e->next;
  }
}

inline struct elem *
mkelem (const char *txt)
{
  struct elem *res = (typeof(res))malloc(sizeof(*res));
  res->data = strdup(txt);
  res->next = 0;
  return res;
}

// не вызывать с самомодифицирующимся аргументом l !!!    
#define push_list(l,e) ({typeof (l) _e = (e); (_e)->next = (l); (l) = (_e);})
#define pop_list(l) ({typeof (l) _res = (l); (l) = (l) ? (l)->next: 0; _res;})

int
main ()
{
  struct list li;
  li.head = li.tail = 0; // init

  // первый элемент в список
  struct elem *el = add_head(&li, mkelem("elem2"));
  // добавим еще в голову и в конец
  add_head(&li, mkelem("elem1"));
  add_tail(&li, mkelem("elem3"));
  prilist("part:", el); // печатаем от "середины" до конца списка
  prilist("full:", li.head); // печатаем весь список
  // теперь удалим голову и хвост
  del_head(&li);
  del_tail(&li);
  prilist("mid:", li.head); // печатаем весь список
  // опять добавим голову и в конец
  add_head(&li, mkelem("elem1"));
  add_tail(&li, mkelem("elem3"));
  prilist("new list:", li.head); // печатаем весь список
  // удалим все и проверим печатью
  while(del_head(&li));
  prilist("after while(del_head()):", li.head);
  // новый список из 2-х элементов 
  add_head(&li, mkelem("elem1"));
  add_tail(&li, mkelem("elem3"));
  do 
    prilist("new del tail list:", li.head);
  // печатаем удаляя с конца
  while(del_tail(&li));
  prilist("after while(del_tail()):", li.head);

  struct elem *sl = 0;
  push_list(sl, mkelem("item1"));
  push_list(sl, mkelem("item2"));
  push_list(sl, mkelem("item3"));
  prilist("prilist() stack list:", sl);
  puts("print while pop()");
  while (el = pop_list(sl))
    puts(el->data);
  prilist("realy empty", sl);
}
```

Код компилируется как gcc, так и g++, но тщательно не тестировался, его части "надерганы" из разных контекстов (надеюсь работоспособных :)), так что заранее приношу извинения за возможные ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

```
link* temp = new link;
temp = first;
```

Утечка