# Добавление в список элемента с помощью функции

Tags: c++, список

Учусь работать со структурами. Хочу реализовать добавление элемента с помощью функции `AddNewElement()`;
Но программа не компилируется. Хотя если этот кусок кода из функции перенести в саму инициализацию(`Init()`), он отрабатывает нормально. Судя по всему проблема с `end`. Но как разобраться с ней, не могу сообразить.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    char* name;
    int age;
};

struct List {
    Student student;
    List* next;
};

void Print(List *begin)
{
    List* print = begin;
    while(print)
    {
        cout <<print->student.name<<"->"<<print->student.age<<endl;
        print = print->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}
void AddNewElement(char* NewName, int NewAge)
{
    end ->next = new List;
    end = end->next;
    end -> student.name = NewName;
    end -> student.age = NewAge;
    end ->next = NULL;
}
void Init(List **begin)
{
    *begin = new List;
    (*begin) -> student.name = "Andrew";
    (*begin) -> student.age = 20;
    (*begin) -> next = NULL;

    List* end = *begin;

    AddNewElement("Petr", 19);
}
int main()
{
    List *begin = NULL;
    Init(&begin);
    Print(begin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ошибку выдает типа overloaded function with no contextual type information.

Comment: Тут уже было полно подобных вопросов. Можете ознакомится с ответами, например, но [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244319/%D0%92%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое, это изменить ваш код на такой:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    char* name;
    int age;
};

struct List {
    Student student;
    List* next;
};

void Print(List *begin)
{
    List* print = begin;
    while(print)
    {
        cout <<print->student.name<<"->"<<print->student.age<<endl;
        print = print->next;
    }
    cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
}
void AddNewElement(List *end, char* NewName, int NewAge)
{
    end ->next = new List;
    end = end->next;
    end -> student.name = NewName;
    end -> student.age = NewAge;
    end ->next = NULL;
}
List *Init(List **begin)
{
    *begin = new List;
    (*begin) -> student.name = "Andrew";
    (*begin) -> student.age = 20;
    (*begin) -> next = NULL;

    return *begin;
}
int main()
{
    List *begin = NULL;
    List *end = Init(&begin);
    AddNewElement(end, "Petr", 19);
    Print(begin);
    return 0;
}
```

[Работающий пример](https://ideone.com/rNlLGJ) и его вывод:

```
Andrew->20
Petr->19
NULL
```

**UPD** (на комментарий 1)

Как отметил Harry, функция `AddNewElement` использует переменную `end` - указатель на конец списка. Но проблема в том, что эта переменная не находится в области видимости функции `AddNewElement`. Тут есть два варианта, либо её объявить глобально, либо передавать как параметр. Последнее более по 'феншую'. Ну тут возникает другая проблема: `end` у вас определяется в функции `Init` как локальная. Но мы ведь делаем инициализацию списка один раз? Почему бы функции инициализации не возвратить все необходимые данные для дальнейшей работы со списком? Вот собственно она это и делает.

**UPD** (на комментарий 2)

Измените

```
void AddNewElement(List *end, char* NewName, int NewAge)
```

на

```
List *AddNewElement(List *end, char* NewName, int NewAge)
```

а в конец функции добавьте

```
 return end;
```

ну и добавление элементов делать так

```
end = AddNewElement(end, "Petr", 19);
```

Вот что бы избежать всех этих 'возратов', лучше делать на классах. тогда `end` можно будет сделать переменной класса и спокойно работать с ней из методов.

Comment: А можно подробней, зачем мы инициализацию переделали, в ф-ию с возвращаемым значением?

Comment: Всё равно работает не так как надо. При добавлении ещё одного элемента, он не стает в конец, а перезаписывает второй.

Comment: @V. Rotenberh, посмотрите дополнения к ответу.

Comment: Всё работает как надо. Спасибо. Буду изучать дальше.

Answer (score 2):

```
void AddNewElement(char* NewName, int NewAge)
{
    end ->next = new List;
    end = end->next;
    end -> student.name = NewName;
    end -> student.age = NewAge;
    end ->next = NULL;
}
```

У вас тут вообще переменная `end` не объявлена! Откуда ж компилятору знать, что вы от него хотите? :)

Смотрите - вы передаете функции имя и возраст. Все, студент есть. Но **В КАКОЙ СПИСОК** его вносить? вы об этом ничего не говорите...

Comment: Спасибо. Поработаю с примером, который ответил @Embedder